# Is this condition correct for right hand thumb rule?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

If the three vectors A,B and C satisfy the relation A⋅B=0 and A⋅C=0, then vector A is parallel to :

correct answer is : B x C
Below , I have made is the diagram for the above Q. There are two possible condition I see for N vector here.

1. When both C and B vector are present at Y axis and are perpendicular to A vector which is at X axis.
2. One of the vectors either C or B(In my diagram , I chose B) is present at Z axis.

Form : 1) A.B=0 , A.C=0. Conditions are met. Now , to check if B x C is parallel to A vector. I get direction for B x C perpendicular to the plane using right hand thumb rule . Therefore , it is not parallel to A which is a wrong answer.

2. Here , A.B=0 , A.C=0 & also , B.C=0. When I use right hand thumb rule here , I get B x C parallel to vector A.

My Q here is that :

1. Can we say this is a condition for right hand thumb rule where angle between two vectors is less than 180. That’s why my 1st case isn’t working.

[image]

Edit: Right hand thumb rule :

[image]

Comment: What "right hand thumb rule" did you learn? There are many versions sufficiently distinct, so provide the rule **you** are referring to.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 The RHTR to find direction for vector cross product.

Comment: Okay, I seem to get your question now. Note that $|\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}|=ab\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. Do you see what $\theta$ is for the first scenario?

Comment: Theta is 90 for each A&B , A&C. But since we are using our right hand thumb rule. Therefore , i think it is 180 degree.

Comment: You sure can use the rule, but do you realise that the "smallest included angle" can be taken from both sides giving ambiguity? That's essentially the fact that the product is $\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Didn’t get this point of yours.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I think you have got my Q. It will be much better for me and other users as well if you write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the rule. It says to curl the fingers around the **smaller** angle between the vectors. The two angles here are the same, $180^\circ$. So, you can curl your fingers in two directions both of which are valid, and give **different** directions. With an angle less than $180^\circ$, this ambiguity wouldn't have arisen.

Why does this happen? Because the magnitude of the product $bc\sin\theta$ becomes $0$ when $\theta=180^\circ$ implying overall $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{0}$ and the null vector has an arbitrary direction, hence the rule giving you two directions.

And as for the problem, we consider $\mathbf{0}$ to be parallel, perpendicular or antiparallel to every vector because it has an arbitrary direction.

Hope this was helpful. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is implying that two vectors being anti-parallel is regarded as being parallel.

In your first scenario, since $B$ and $C$ are anti-parallel to each other, $B\times C=\vec{0}$. Since all vectors are parallel to the zero vector, we have that $A$ is parallel to $B\times C$.

As for the original problem, since $A\cdot B=A\cdot C=0$, we get that $A$ is perpendicular to $B$ and $C$. Therefore, $A$ should be parallel to the vector perpendicular to $B$ and $C$, which is $B\times C$.

Comment: I think it'll be better if you use vectorheads ```\vector{A}``` or boldface ```\mathbf{A}```.

Comment: What do you think about the Q i have in my post ? Can you use the right hand thumb rule when theta = 180 ?

Comment: @S.M.T: The right hand rule, as I said, can be defined in different ways. The one I prefer says that the angle must be $0<\theta<180^\circ$, and as the product vanishes at $0$ and $180^\circ$, there is no need for the rule.